# SQL Server - selecting an item based on the previous counter value (same foreign key)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure how to word this above so hopefully this will explain it better. I currently have a table of data as follows which is fetched using this query (the query is looking at a view)

CODE

```
SELECT
AppRunningPercentages.ProjectID,
AppRunningPercentages.AppID,
AppRunningPercentages.AppCounter,
AppRunningPercentages.PercentageComplete,
RunningPercentage= NULL
from AppRunningPercentages
where ProjectID = 123
```

DATA

```
ProjectID(FK)     AppID       AppCounter     PercentageComplete    RunningPercentage
   123              1              1                 50% 
   123              4              2                 40% 
   123              7              3                 10%
```

Based on my SELECT Statement the values above are shown, however I unsure on how to display the RunningPercentage. based on the above scenario I would like the table below to calculate them as follows within the same SELECT statement however I am unsure on how I can achieve this running total.

```
RunningPercentage
       0%     
       50%
       90%
```

when the **AppCounter = 1**, then I want the RunningPercentage to display as 0. This is so I can calculate a value correctly to the current percentage. It is effectively adding the previous percentages together, so when AppCounter = 1, then it is looking for an AppCounter with the value of 0.

- When **AppCounter = 2**, it will add the 0% and the 50% together  (50%)
- When **AppCounter = 3**, it will add the 0%, 50% and 40% together (90%)
  ......And so on

Thankyou for any help with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(PercentageComplete) over (partition by projectid
                                      order by appcounter
                                     ) - PercentageComplete
       ) as RunningPercentage
from t;
```

Note:  you can use a `rows between` clause instead of subtracting the value in the current row.  I find subtracting the value in the current row to be simpler for this logic.

In early versions, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(RunningPercentage, 0)
from t outer apply
     (select sum(PercentageComplete) as RunningPercentage
      from t t2
      where t2.projectid = t.projectid and t2.appcounter < t.appcounter
     ) t2;
```

Comment: spot on, thankyou, I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me